# Template Variables do not update from default values

Tags: modx

I'm new to ModX, but I have created a Template Variable (TV) for an Image ( image-1 ) .

Then I set a default value, and assign the TV to my Home_Template, click save.

Create some simple html in that template:

```
<li>[*image-1*]</li>
```

As expected, the template variable is available on this screen. So I select the image I want to display, and save. It appears in the preview for this template screen, but not on the actual website.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your caching settings ~ probably best to turn off caching completely during development.

also try calling your snippets & variables as 'uncached' ex:

```
[!*image*]
```

this looks like evolution code, best to switch to revolution if at all possible.

-sean